# Can PHP access Active Directory username in all browsers?

Tags: php, active-directory

I'm running PHP on a Windows server (xammp install), not on IIS.

Is there any sort of mod that can be installed for Apache that will allow me to grab the users Active Directory username?

Comment: What does that have to do with browsers?

Comment: @feeela, some browsers support certain REQUEST variables while others don't. He's looking for one that won't discriminate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Apache's mod_auth_sspi.

It does not, however work out of the box in all browsers.

- Internet Explorer, being a Microsoft product will automatically log you in, if you're using AD Domain authentication and if not - will fall back to asking you for your username and password.
- Firefox and Chrome will ask you for your username and password and I think that they both can be configured to act as IE, but will require some tweaking.
- Opera will have problems passing creditenials, unless you specifically configure the module to always use Basic HTTP auth.

Comment: Perfect - Thank you. It actually seems to be working well in Chrome as well as IE.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into mod_authnz_ldap

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html